# How to find out which Safari tab is using massive memory?

Tags: macos, safari, memory, performance

As described in my [other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/125288/5887), Safari on OS X 10.6. is causing me massive problems (with my way of working like having many tabs in Safari open for a long time).

I just realized that after closing some (few!) of the many open tabs, *instantly*

- it became **quiet** - the cooling fan of the macbook was not spinning any more
- and I had **>1 GB more free RAM** (which is a lot, as I have only 3 GB in total)!!

It seems, that like very often in real life, **Pareto's law** applies:
**20% of my open tabs might consume 80% of the ressources!**

So my question:

- is there a way to identify those few tabs which cause safari to consume hardware ressources like crazy without closing them - maybe by analyzing the `Safari Web Content` process?

Comment: Of interest might be [How can I figure out which tab in Safari is using CPU?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45768/) and [Safari using too much RAM](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2910/)

Comment: Apart from the general case in the duplicate which seems to have no answer also see this [answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/4131/237) which suggests Flash is the main culprit

Comment: @mark. I should have thanked you for the link. Cross linking in comments is excellent whether they are dupe or not. I'll clean up the comments here once we get the links reworded

Answer (score 11):

Open the Activity monitor in Utility folder.

> Sort by name
>
> View by memory usage

You should see individual Safari pages memory consumption.

[image]

By hovering pointer over one will show the web site name.

The memory consumption will depend on the web site it self, its design, the complexity, and multimedia usage.

Comment: I'm using OS 10.6.8 - are you sure that I can list the memory consumption of single safari tabs there also?

Comment: This seems to be incorrect for at least 10.8 and older; please add what version this works on.